# Is there any information on who did the RPOP prop/effect for Space Cowboys?

Tags: props, effects

Midway through the movie *Space Cowboys* (2000), while they're rendezvousing with a satellite, the computer prop / program effects in the following screenshot show up.
[image: RPOP Mockup in Space Cowboys, on a Macintosh Powerbook G3]

This is a surprisingly accurate version of [RPOP 6](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110023479.pdf) (the Rendezvous and Proximity Operations Program, see page 239). I worked on RPOP 7 and 8, and so I'm fascinated about some of the little differences and choices that were made in making this--there's some obvious for-the-audience changes, like making it something like a top-down radar display--others I suppose are production-related, like putting it on a Mac laptop instead of a Windows one.

I know it's a longshot, but is there any publicly-available information on who worked on this particular prop / effect and what decision they made? My next best idea is to try to ask Adam Savage.

Comment: Could you explain what RPOP actually is, without me having to Google it (“Radiation Protection of Patients”?) or your recommendation of scrolling through 239 pages of a dense and technical looking document?

Comment: @Darren It's the Rendezvous and Proximity Operations Program; it helps astronauts monitor rendezvous between two spacecraft by displaying how they'll move relative to each other and, on the space shuttle, the control inputs to use to navigate to where they want to go.  But searching through the document for RPOP might be instructive if you really want to know.

Comment: Whilst under normal circumstances I might be interested, this is a Stack for TV and movie buffs, not space and astronautics. An image of the real system compared to the prop one would also improve this question, IMO.

Comment: @Darren ???? you asked me to explain what it actually is, then criticize me for doing so?

Comment: No, that was in response to this suggestion "But searching through the document for RPOP might be instructive if you really want to know."

Comment: Meaning; not everyone will have the time or desire to learn about real-life space craft operations in order to appreciate your question, or possibly even answer it.

Comment: @ErinAnne - actually, your best bet is Liz Radley, as Video and Computer Graphics Supervisor - she leads the team that puts graphics on the computer displays, and shes a fan of Apple, and also works with Clint Eastwood a lot, and also does camera op duties herself. Was probably a bit of to-ing and fro-ing with NASA to get a version that they could use onscreen, that is both modified by them and considered ok for public. Most I have seen end up as video files that they can just run looped or triggered when they need to, so platform didnt matter.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby Thanks, that seems like a decent lead to try to run down. Since part of my question was "who," if you make it an answer I'll upvote it, and maybe accept it if I can't get more of a story elsewhere